# Prestashop 1.6 override module's CSS

Tags: css, prestashop-1.6

I'm struggling for quite a while but without any obvious success..
I'm trying to override the blocktopmenu css files in a custom theme
I've done everything like this:

1. added in themes/{my_theme}/css/modules/blocktopmenu/css the css
   files with the exact names
2. deleted the cache class
3. turned on the Force Compilation

But still it doesn't work at all.. 
Any ideas on how to solve this topic?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In Advanced Preferences > Performance > CCC (COMBINE, COMPRESS AND CACHE), have you tried disabling " Smart Cache for Css"?

Also, have you cleared you browser cache?

Have a nice day,

Vlad